How to Implement Continuous State Switching with Spacebar in ncurses?
So i made this project called the Hassan Doodles which is just like my own version of Google Doodles but it didn't turn out how i wanted it as it failed to run the function
Here is the code
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display_initial_message() {
    clear();
    mvprintw(25, 104, "Presenting the Hassan Doodles");
    mvprintw(26, 104, "Press spacebar to continue or 'q' to quit");
    refresh();
}

void display_first_program() {
    clear();
    mvprintw(1, 104, "My First Program");
    mvprintw(25, 104, "print('Hello World')");
    mvprintw(30, 104, "Like all people I had humble beginnings like this python WOW!");
    refresh();
}

void display_ocean_gpt() {
    clear();
    mvprintw(1, 104, "My First Team Project");
    mvprintw(25, 104, "OceanGPT");
    mvprintw(30, 104, "So I must tell you OceanGPT is not a GPT but just a long IO program. I know :(");
    refresh();
}

void display_ai_revolution() {
    clear();
    mvprintw(1, 104, "AI Revolution");
    mvprintw(25, 104, "A Real AI");
    mvprintw(30, 104, "This was when Tensorflow, Keras and Scikit Learn made me create actual AI so wow! I AM SMART ;)");
    refresh();
}
void display_sklearn(){
    clear();
    mvprintw(1, 104, "Scikit Learn Movement");
    mvprintw(25, 104, "import sklearn");
    mvprintw(30, 104, "Man so this one line made a whole .py file full to the brim and scikit-learn was sick :)");
    refresh();
}

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);  // Enable capturing special keys

    enum {INITIAL, FIRST_PROGRAM, OCEAN_GPT, AI_REVOLUTION, SKLEARN_MOVEMENT} state = INITIAL;

    int ch;

    display_initial_message();

    while (1) {
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == 'q') {
            break;
        } else if (ch == ' ') {
            switch (state) {
                case INITIAL:
                    display_first_program();
                    state = FIRST_PROGRAM;
                    break;
                case FIRST_PROGRAM:
                    display_ocean_gpt();
                    state = OCEAN_GPT;
                    break;
                case OCEAN_GPT:
                    display_ai_revolution();
                    state = AI_REVOLUTION;
                    break;
                case AI_REVOLUTION:
                    display_initial_message();
                    state = INITIAL;
                    break;
        case SKLEARN_MOVEMENT:
            display_sklearn();
            state = SKLEARN_MOVEMENT;
            }
        }
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}



I made it so that it would run a function once it was there turn but it didn't do the sklearn_movement for some reason so when i press spacebar it would go back to the beginning instead of going to Sklearn_movement

case AI_REVOLUTION: ...; state = INITIAL; You never go to the SKLEARN_MOVEMENT state. And when you do, you never leave it. One minute in a debugger should have told you this.

Considering the indentation difference for SKLEARN_MOVEMENT, did you add that state after everything else? Then it's likely that you just forgot to change the assignment in the AI_REVOLUTION state.

Thank you so much i forgot about it clumsy me Thank you
